# ember-custom-actions addon urlForCustomAction not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

I am trying to use ember-customer-actions(v2.1.0) addon with my ember version = 3.1.4.
It is really a cool addon and ease our life while implementing customer actions and urls.

It's configuration say to override this method 'urlForCustomAction' to complete override the url and even avoid model name.

I integrated it as doc says.
I posted my issue here as well.

This is my adapter code:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application'; 

import { AdapterMixin } from 'ember-custom-actions';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend(AdapterMixin,{

urlForCustomAction(modelName, id, snapshot, actionId, queryParams) {

return 'domain.com/resetPassword';

}

});
```

It seems like something is missing or may be there is a bug in addon or may be this addon is in beta phase.

I need quick help on this, if anyone has already used it then please share your experience thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try adding super call before the return statement.

```
urlForCustomAction(modelName, id, snapshot, actionId, queryParams) {

    this._super(...arguments);
    return 'domain.com/resetPassword';

}
```